# Python 2.7 json array and indexes

Tags: python-2.7

Im reviewing code and there is a line that i am unsure if im reading it correctly.

Here it is:

Data['coords'] [0] [1]

If im understanding correctly the first item is the json array and the second , third refer to indexes in the array. Am i correct or completely out to left field?

Comment: Without seeing the JSON, it's impossible to say for sure, but yes, that's seems right. It's just indexing the nested structures.

Comment: Awsome thank you very much the json is holding coordinates for a grid i just wanted to confim that was valid form and was unsure how to search my question with its form.

Comment: Did you test the code? That would have verified it too, or at least reinforced that you probably had the right solution.

Comment: Havent yet just reading over notes from class i was pretty vague guess thats something ill work on for second year

Comment: If you use an Android phone, download QPython. It's a free Python interpreter for Android (iOS may have a version too). They're very handy for quickly trying out small pieces of code on the go. Just trying the code out is a almost always the best way of understanding it.